# Rails selecting a field in grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using this code in my view to create a selection `grouped_collection_select(:query, :city_id, @states, :cities, :name, :id, :name, {:selected => "Chicago"})` that looks like this: [image]

I want to have "Chicago" selected by default.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Note for other answerers: setting `:selected` to the city's id (not name) doesn't work.

Comment: @dax No, I ended up just adding a default "Please select location" type of option http://weekaway.com

Answer (score 3):

Hi on your sample above you can select "Chicago" by defining the selected key index of chicago.

Here's an example:

```
 @city_group =
                 [
                 ["Wisoncin", [["Lake Geneva", "1"], 
                 ["Elkhart Lake", "2"]]],
                 ["Michigan", [["Harbor Country", "3"], ["Traverse City", "4"]]],
                 ["Indiana", [["Bloomington", "5"], ["Valparaiso", "6"]]],
                 ["Minnesota", [["Twin Cities", 
                 "7"], ["Bloomington", "8"], ["Stillwater", 
                 "9"]]],
                 ["Florida", [["Sanibel & Captiva", "10"]]],
                 ["Illinois", [["Chicago", "11"], 
                 ["Galena", "12"]]],
                 ]
```

and in your views add this:

```
<%= select_tag(:brand_id, grouped_options_for_select(@city_group, selected_key = "11", prompt = nil)) %>
```

Hope it helps! Enjoy!

Comment: selected_key = "" is just what I was looking for. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution: 1**

```
city = City.find_by_name("Chicago") 
select(:query, :city_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@states,
           :cities, :name, :id, :name, city.id))
```

**Solution: 2**

```
city_obj = City.find_by_name("Chicago") 
grouped_collection_select(:query, :id, @states, :cities, :name, :id, :name, 
                         {:object => city_obj})
```

**Solution: 3**

```
@city = City.find_by_name("Chicago")
grouped_collection_select(:city, :id, @states, :cities, :name, :id, :name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pre-select an option, but it's not very clear in the documentation. The first parameter (here `:city`) has to be the name of an instance variable defined on `self`. The object stored in that instance variable has to have a method named after the second parameter (here: `:id`). Now `@city.id` should return the id of the city you want to have selected.

```
@city = City.find_by_name("Chicago")
grouped_collection_select(:city, :id, @states, :cities, :name, :id, :name)
```

I made you [a gist](https://gist.github.com/tessi/5505930) with a slightly different example for better understanding. Note: the gist should be executed in a rails console, so that the `include` works

Comment: I think `City.find_by_name("Chicago")` is a bit more idiomatic.