# Is it possible to validate a grouped_collection_select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model-view-controller, activerecord

I am working on a Rails app where users can post Quotes about different art forms (e.g. Music, Painting, Photography, etc.). Each `Quote` must be assigned a `Medium` (such as Music or Photography) and a `Genre` (such as Jazz or Rock and Roll for music or Landscape for photography).

I am using a `grouped_collection_select` for the Genre field on my Quote form, and that works great to sort the genres, but I'd like to prevent anyone from selecting a genre that doesn't belong to the medium they have selected.

I know that I can do this dynamically with javascript, as in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?autoplay=true), but I'd like to create a validation to ensure that no bad data gets into the database.

Is there a way to validate this in my `Quote` model so that there's no way a `Quote` can be saved with a genre that does not have the correct medium? This would prevent someone from saving something that is the medium "Photography" and the genre "Jazz", for instance.

Here are my models:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :medium
  belongs_to :genre
end

class Medium < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quotes
  has_many :genres
end

class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :quotes
  belongs_to :medium
end
```

And here are the fields on my Quote form:

```
<%= f.label :medium, 'Medium' %>
<%= f.collection_select :medium_id, Medium.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: 'Select a medium'}, {class: 'form-control'} %>

<%= f.label :genre, 'Genre' %>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :genre_id, Medium.order(:name), :genres, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: 'Select a genre'}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
```

Comment: First instinct is to suggest a custom validation, where you find and pluck the array `:id` and `:medium_id` form `Genre`. The pair `medium_id` and `genre_id` should be included in this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rails `validate` method to achieve this,

```
validate: check_medium
def check_medium
  errors.add(:base, "Your error message") if genre.try(:medium) != medium
end
```

Comment: That answered my question precisely, so accepting this answer, but I think I agree with [ahawrylak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6376149/ahawrylak) about changing the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal here is to story only `genre_id` in `quotes` table. This `belongs_to :medium` is unnecessary because each genre already knows its medium. With architecture like this, you don't have to worry about medium-genre mismatch at all. Models:

```
class Quote
  belongs_to :genre

  # With delegation you still can do something like quote.medium
  delegate :medium, to: :genre
end

class Medium
  has_many :genres
  has_many :quotes, through: :genres
end

class Genre
  belongs_to :medium
  has_many :quotes
end
```

Comment: I guess the drawback to this is that I don't want people to have to sort through all of the genres that don't belong to the medium. Would the collection select still work?

Comment: `Medium`-`Genre` relationship wouldn't change so your select should work exactly as before. You can try to fill `genre` select options based on `medium` select or leave just one grouped select. There are nice examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307965/rails-selecting-a-field-in-grouped-collection-select)

Comment: Ok this makes sense. I guess the architecture you suggest is more of my intent on the database level, so that is a better way to define it in the model. As for the user-experience, if I would like them to choose their "Medium" first it could still filter out the results of the genre select in the browser but degrade gracefully to just selecting the genre from the grouped_collection_select if javascript is turned off.